# how to iterate over ant properties and pass as arg to exec

Tags: ant

I have a properties file and I want to pass all key and values to a command, how can I do that?

say the property file looks file

```
size=small
perf=true
```

and the ant task looks like

```
    <exec executable="${prog}" failonerror="true">
<!-- I want to add all properties from file as argument here, -->
    </exec>
```

so that at runtime, the behavior isidentical to

```
<exec executable="${prog}" failonerror="true">
   <arg value = "size"/>
   <arg value = "small"/>
   <arg value = "perf"/>
   <arg value = "true"/>
</exec>
```

how can I do that?
Thanks

EDIT:

following Vadzim's suggestion, I am using script now.

```
<property file="test.properties" prefix="testproperty"/>
<target name = "test1">
<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
  properties = project.getUserProperties()
  echo = project.createTask( "echo" );
  anotation = project.getProperty("testproperty.size")
  echo.setMessage(anotation);
  echo.perform();
  for(key in properties) {
    echo.setMessage(key);
    echo.perform();
    echo.setMessage(properties[key]);
    echo.perform();
  }
]]> </script>
</target>
```

However, getProperty() is working, but getProperties contains only java functions like notify()

```
$ant test1
test1:
     [echo] small
     [echo] notifyAll
     [echo] function notifyAll() {/*
     [echo] void notifyAll()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] values
     [echo] function values() {/*
     [echo] java.util.Collection values()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] containsKey
     [echo] function containsKey() {/*
     [echo] boolean containsKey(java.lang.Object)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] entrySet
     [echo] function entrySet() {/*
     [echo] java.util.Set entrySet()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] keySet
     [echo] function keySet() {/*
     [echo] java.util.Set keySet()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] put
     [echo] function put() {/*
     [echo] java.lang.Object put(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] contains
     [echo] function contains() {/*
     [echo] boolean contains(java.lang.Object)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] empty
     [echo] false
     [echo] equals
     [echo] function equals() {/*
     [echo] boolean equals(java.lang.Object)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] notify
     [echo] function notify() {/*
     [echo] void notify()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] class
     [echo] class java.util.Hashtable
     [echo] elements
     [echo] function elements() {/*
     [echo] java.util.Enumeration elements()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] keys
     [echo] function keys() {/*
     [echo] java.util.Enumeration keys()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] isEmpty
     [echo] function isEmpty() {/*
     [echo] boolean isEmpty()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] size
     [echo] function size() {/*
     [echo] int size()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] putAll
     [echo] function putAll() {/*
     [echo] void putAll(java.util.Map)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] clear
     [echo] function clear() {/*
     [echo] void clear()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] wait
     [echo] function wait() {/*
     [echo] void wait()
     [echo] void wait(long)
     [echo] void wait(long,int)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] containsValue
     [echo] function containsValue() {/*
     [echo] boolean containsValue(java.lang.Object)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] toString
     [echo] function toString() {/*
     [echo] java.lang.String toString()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] hashCode
     [echo] function hashCode() {/*
     [echo] int hashCode()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] clone
     [echo] function clone() {/*
     [echo] java.lang.Object clone()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] get
     [echo] function get() {/*
     [echo] java.lang.Object get(java.lang.Object)
     [echo] */}
     [echo] getClass
     [echo] function getClass() {/*
     [echo] java.lang.Class getClass()
     [echo] */}
     [echo] remove
     [echo] function remove() {/*
     [echo] java.lang.Object remove(java.lang.Object)
     [echo] */}

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

What's the correct way to iterate getProperties()'s result?

Any suggestions are greatly appreicated

EDIT2:

[jbeard4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366856/jbeard4) has an excellent explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481911/302959). about the javascript issue.
so the correct way would be

```
<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
  properties = project.getUserProperties()
  var keyIter = properties.keySet().iterator();
  while(keyIter.hasNext()) {
    var key = keyIter.next();
    var value = properties.get(key);
    echo.setMessage(key+value);
    echo.perform();
  }
]]> </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved only with custom [script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) code.

See for example [Is it possible to call ant task from a javascript scriptdef task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608430/is-it-possible-to-call-ant-task-from-a-javascript-scriptdef-task).

Just iterate over [project.getProperties()](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.html#getProperties%28%29) and add exec args [through API](http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/en/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/ExecTask.html#createArg%28%29).

Comment: Thanks, that make sense, however getProperties/getUserProperties only returns a set of java functions to me. getProperty seems working